# Calculating the Image of a Set (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

When trying to find the image of a subset, how does one perform the relevant calculation?  For example, if $f$ maps $R$ into $R$ by $f(x)=x^2$, if I input $[0,2]$ I should get $[0,4]$.  If I input $[-1,2]$ I should also get $[0,4]$ and if I input the union of $[-3,-2]$ and $[1,2]$ I should get $[1,9]$ (according to the text), but I am entirely unsure as to how to get these answers.

Comment: You could start with something like "Let $x\in [0,2]$, then $x^2\in [0,4]$..."

Answer (score 1):

For $[-1,2]$, you have that $[-1,0]\cup[0,2]$. The function $f:x\longmapsto x^2$ is bijective (and decreasing) on $[-1,0]$ and thus $f([-1,0])=[f(0),f(-1)]=[0,1]$ and also bijective on $[0,2]$ (and increasing), therefore,
$$f([0,2])=[f(0),f(2)]=[0,4].$$ Finally, since $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$ for every function, you finally get
$$f([-1,2])=f([-1,0]\cup [0,2])=f([-1,0])\cup f([0,2])=[0,1]\cup [0,4]=[0,4].$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no general algorithm; it depends on the situation. Here we may use the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and strictly decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^-$ to say that, for instance, $1 \leq x \leq 2 \iff 1 \leq f(x) \leq 4$ and $-3 \leq x \leq -2 \iff 9 \geq f(x) \geq 4$. This shows that the image of $[-3,2] \cup [1,2]$ is precisely $[1,9]$.